# Why is my `brew list` gets populated b unknown libraries and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: homebrew

My mac is 1 month old, i've been installing all I can with `brew` and `brew cask` to keep things in order, to be able to uninstall unnecessary software completely. Brew cask list seems ok, only the libraries I have actually isntalled are listed. I've installed maybe ~10 libraries with `brew install`. Why is my list looks like this now??? How do I get rid of the unnecessary libraries without breaking stuff?

```
adns            gettext         lame            libgpg-error        libtiff         mongodb-community   openjpeg        readline        theora          yarn
aom         giflib          leptonica       libidn2         libunistring        mongodb-community-shell openssl@1.1     ripgrep         uchardet        z
cairo           glib            libarchive      libksba         libusb          mujs            opus            rtmpdump        unbound         zimg
flac            gmp         libass          libogg          libvidstab      ncurses         p11-kit         rubberband      vapoursynth     zsh
fontconfig      gnutls          libassuan       libpng          libvorbis       nettle          pcre            sdl2            webp            zsh-completions
freetype        graphite2       libbluray       libsamplerate       libvpx          node            pcre2           snappy          x264            zsh-git-prompt
frei0r          harfbuzz        libevent        libsndfile      little-cms2     node@10         pinentry        speex           x265            zsh-syntax-highlighting
fribidi         icu4c           libffi          libsoxr         lua@5.1         npth            pixman          sqlite          xvid
gdbm            jpeg            libgcrypt       libtasn1        lzo         opencore-amr        python          tesseract       xz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some formulae require, or depend on others. You can see which other formulae `formula X` depends on with:

```
brew deps X
```

You can see which other formulae need `formula X` with:

```
brew uses X --installed
```

You can see formulae which no-one depends on with:

```
brew leaves
```

In general, you can try removing any formula because it will not remove anything that is required by something else unless you use:

```
brew rm --ignore-dependencies  ...
```